# deslocamento de todos os valores dos elementos para a posição seguinte, último valor deve estar na primeira posição

Tags: c

boa tarde, alguém pode me ajudar a desenvolver essa questão?
(c) rotação dos elementos do vetor, com o deslocamento de todos os valores dos elementos
para a posição seguinte, exceto o último valor, que deve ser colocado na posição
do primeiro elemento;
havia utilizado v[i]=v[i+1];, mas não ta dando certo, gostaria que fosse tipo:
(supondo que o tam. do vetor seja 9) e os valores fossem: 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 e quero que imprima 9 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, mas esta imprimindo 9 10 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, segue anexo o que fiz até agora:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int v[10]; int soma=0; int val; int qtd = 0;
    v[10] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
        soma += v[i];
        if(v[i]==0) {
            printf("Digite um numero maior que 0.\n");
            scanf("%d", &v[i]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }

    printf("\nSoma: %d\n", soma);
    int aux = v[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        if (i==0) {
            v[i] = v[8];
        }
        if (i==8) {
            v[1] = aux;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }

    printf("\nInforme o valor para verificar se existe no vetor.\n");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        if (val == v[i]) {
            qtd++;
        }
    }
    printf("Quantidade de vezes em que aparece no vetor: %d\n", qtd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer é fazer um right shift no vetor. O código para fazer isso é esse, sendo n o numero de elemtos do vetor:

```
    temp=a[n-1];
    for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        a[i]=a[i-1];
    }
    a[0]=temp;
```